# Solving the reccurence method by using substitution

Tags: induction, computational-complexity, substitution

I am having trouble in understanding this example(as the attached the picture below). I basically have 2 questions which these questions are related to each other.

1. Is **T(N) for N = 1** must equal to **1** for any reccurences case in substitution method by using induction(in basis step)?
2. If it is not, then why in the example is equal to 1?
   Because if I put N = 1 to the 
   **>> T(N)=2T(N/2)+N** the result is not equal to 1 instead of 2.

Can someone explain? [Example of attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUa7z.png)

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be $1.$  This is the problem statement.  It might be anything.

Comment: @saulspatz I just noticed it was a problem statement. So is it somekind of hint to guess the answer quicker?

Comment: No, not at all.  This is the data for the problem to be solved.  We have a function $T$ that obeys the two equations equations given, and we want to find an explicit formula for $T$.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah I see. I am actually use this example to solve other reccurence problem which only has 1 equation with similar problem. That is why I am confused by this example but thanks for your explanation, indeed.